# How to retrieve all NFTs owned by a wallet

Tags: web3.js, metaplex, metaplex-js

Given a specific public key of a wallet, how do I get all NFTs that the wallet owns?

Calling Metaplex doesn't work, it always returns the NFTs of a specific wallet I can't understand why even though I provide a different wallet on multiple attempts.

Comment: How did you try to get the NFTs through metaplex?

Answer (score 2):

The Method that I would recommend is using the metaplex JS SDK.

This example is ripped from [Solana Cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/nfts.html#how-to-get-all-nfts-from-a-wallet).

```
import { Metaplex, keypairIdentity } from "@metaplex-foundation/js";
import { Connection, clusterApiUrl, Keypair, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";

(async () => {
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"), "confirmed");
  const keypair = Keypair.generate();

  const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection);
  metaplex.use(keypairIdentity(keypair));

  const owner = new PublicKey("2R4bHmSBHkHAskerTHE6GE1Fxbn31kaD5gHqpsPySVd7");
  const allNFTs = await metaplex.nfts().findAllByOwner(owner);

  console.log(allNFTs);
})();
```

This example will only work locally, since it's using the keypair identity it will only work locally. Instead you can also use the connected wallets identity (e.g. like in [this metaplex example](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js-examples/tree/main/connect-wallet)). If you then want to find all NFTs of that wallet just call `findAllByOwner(metaplex.identity().publicKey)`

Comment: this method doesn't work, because no matter which wallet owner you specify, the returned NFT list is always from the same NFT wallet. For example if I specify 3 different wallet in 3 different tries, metaplex return the NFT list of the same wallet each time, and this wallet is not even one of the 3 that was tested.

Comment: Also mainnet-beta rpc refuses the connection with this kind of request

Comment: Are you using exactly this code? Which part are you changing to get different results?

Comment: Also you should never use the default rpc in your programs. It has too many limitations

Comment: `const allNFTs = await metaplex.nfts().findAllByOwner({ owner: owner });`

This worked for me, while the solution above never returned anything.